# How to create a controller method for registration that saves user to a mySQL database

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, authentication, registration

I have a login/registration form in React and I am trying to connect it to a Spring restful endpoint. I’m using a persistent user class and just need basic authentication.

Below is the frontend portion so far. However, I am also having difficulty with my authentication controllers in Spring Boot so I just deleted them.

Can anyone help with a very basic controller method for registration. I’d like one that saves the user to the database (mySQL) via a userRepository and also authenticates login.

```
const Login = () => {

    const [registration, setRegistration] = useState("true");

    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [regPwd, setRegPwd] = useState("");
    const [regUsername, setRegUsername] = useState("");

    const [logUsername, setLogUsername] = useState("");
    const [logPwd, setLogPwd] = useState("");

    const handleRegSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const regUser = {
            email: email,
            username: regUsername,
            password: regPwd
        }
        try {
            const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/registration',
                { regUser })
        }
        catch (error) {

        }
    }

    const handleLogSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const logUser = {
            username: logUsername,
            password: logPwd
        }
        try {
            const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/login',
                { logUser })
        }
        catch (error) {

        }
    }

    const registerForm = (
        <form onSubmit={handleRegSubmit} id="Regform">
            <h1 className="ky">Kale Yeah!</h1>
            <label htmlFor="Email">Email</label>
            <input 
                type="email" 
                placeholder="Email" 
                value={email} 
                onChange = {(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} 
                required />
            <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
            <input 
                type="text" 
                placeholder="Username" 
                value={regUsername} 
                onChange = {(e) => setRegUsername(e.target.value)} 
                required />
            <label htmlFor="Password">Password</label>
            <input 
                type="password" 
                placeholder="Password" 
                value={regPwd} 
                onChange = {(e) => setRegPwd(e.target.value)} 
                required />
            <button type="submit" className="btn">
                Register
            </button>
        </form>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches involved to give to you in a single response, so I recommend you take a look in some tutorials around web, even courses in Udemy, Hotmart, Alura, about React + Spring for CRUD and authentication.

I let to you here [this lecture](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-build-a-fullstack-crud-application-with-react-authentication-part-1-a8c6436feac7).